# collectionview in a uiviewcontroller which is presented as a popover

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipopovercontroller, uicollectionviewdelegate

I got a `UICollectionView` in a view controller which I present as a popover. The thing is I can not scroll horizontally despite the fact that i set the scroll direction to horizontal.

[image: simulator printscreen]

I do have a bouncing only, that is to say I drag with three fingers in my collection view and I can see the presence of more cell at the right, but after I release the scrollview zaps back to initial position as you can see on the picture.

any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: u need to use collection view.,oh wait, are u using collection view ?

Comment: If you are using a UIScrollView: Have you set the contentSize?

Comment: sorry, thanks for the edit, Indeed I use uicollectionview, and No I do not set contentsize